# Доступ к внутреней памяти устройства Android?

Tags: java, android, файлы, исключения, доступ

Всем привет. Вообщем, я пытаюсь в данный момент сделать что то типа файлового менеджера для Android в очень простом виде.

Я работаю с реальным устройством в котором есть внутренняя память и карта памяти.

Доступ к файлам **карте памяти** я получаю по пути `/mnt/sdcard` ну или так `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

Доступ к файлам **памяти устройства** я получаю так `/mnt/sdcard2`

Когда я вставляю скопированный файл в  `/mnt/sdcard` (Внешнее хранилище) всё нормально, всё копируется. 
Но когда я пытаюсь иметь дело с путём начинающимся на 
 `/mnt/sdcard2` (внутреннее хранилище - память устройства) у меня выскакивает IOException `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`.

Разрешения в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Мой код:

```
 private void copy()
    {
        try {
            publishProgress();
            if (!newFile.exists()) {
                if (!isFolder)
                {
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                }

            }
            if (isFolder) {
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(existingFile, newFile);
            }
            else
            {
                FileUtils.copyFile(existingFile, newFile);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = 1;
        }

    }
```

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Это связано с ограничением на доступ к карте введенным начиная с API=KitKat

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Как же тогда работают файловые менеджеры? Например я пользуюсь https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.fileman  и там всё ОК с переименованием и удалением файлов из внутренней памяти устройства